# R: Issue when trying to use 'match' inside mutate for a grouped tbl

Tags: r, match, dplyr

I have a dataframe with an id column and an boolean event column:

```
x <- data.frame(id = c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3), 
             event = c(F,F,F,T,F,F,F,T,F,F,F,T,T))
```

For each `id` I want to create a column next to it with the position where the event is first `TRUE`. So for `id 0` there are no `TRUE`s so I get `NA`, for `id 1` the first element is `TRUE` so I get `1`, for `id 2` I get `2`, and for `id 3` I also get `2`.

Expected output:

```
      id event event_num
   (dbl) (lgl)     (int)
1      0 FALSE        NA
2      0 FALSE        NA
3      0 FALSE        NA
4      1  TRUE         1
5      1 FALSE         1
6      1 FALSE         1
7      2 FALSE         2
8      2  TRUE         2
9      2 FALSE         2
10     2 FALSE         2
11     3 FALSE         2
12     3  TRUE         2
13     3  TRUE         2
```

To try and get this I use the code:

```
x %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(event_num = match(TRUE, event))
```

However this gives me

```
     id event event_num
   (dbl) (lgl)     (int)
1      0 FALSE        NA
2      0 FALSE        NA
3      0 FALSE        NA
4      1  TRUE         1
5      1 FALSE         1
6      1 FALSE         1
7      2 FALSE        NA
8      2  TRUE        NA
9      2 FALSE        NA
10     2 FALSE        NA
11     3 FALSE         2
12     3  TRUE         2
13     3  TRUE         2
```

i.e. `id` 2 has `NA` instead of `2`.

**EDIT**
Updated dplyr to 0.5.0 and it works, was using 0.4.3 before

Comment: If for id 3, you get 3, why it is 2?  I think your condition is not clear

Comment: Check if `match` is being masked by another package. What do you get from `> match` at the console?

Comment: Works for me when I updated dplyr to 0.5.0, was previously using 0.4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `which` and choose the first appearence:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(event_num = which(event)[1])
# Source: local data frame [13 x 3]
# Groups: id [4]
# 
#       id event event_num
#    <dbl> <lgl>     <int>
# 1      0 FALSE        NA
# 2      0 FALSE        NA
# 3      0 FALSE        NA
# 4      1  TRUE         1
# 5      1 FALSE         1
# 6      1 FALSE         1
# 7      2 FALSE         2
# 8      2  TRUE         2
# 9      2 FALSE         2
# 10     2 FALSE         2
# 11     3 FALSE         2
# 12     3  TRUE         2
# 13     3  TRUE         2
```

We can also use `base::match(TRUE, event)`. But I usually avoid matching to boolean elements to vectors.

Comment: Possibly. Or another package is masking `match`. They might want to try `base::match`

Answer (score -1):

We can also use `which.max`

```
x %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(event_num = which.max(event)*NA^all(!event))
   id event event_num
#    <dbl> <lgl>     <dbl>
#1      0 FALSE        NA
#2      0 FALSE        NA
#3      0 FALSE        NA
#4      1  TRUE         1
#5      1 FALSE         1
#6      1 FALSE         1
#7      2 FALSE         2
#8      2  TRUE         2
#9      2 FALSE         2
#10     2 FALSE         2
#11     3 FALSE         2
#12     3  TRUE         2
#13     3  TRUE         2
```